# What does "cut the cheese " mean?

Tags: idioms, slang

I want to know the meaning in this sentence :

> " Sorry isn't gonna **cut the cheese** this time "

the meaning of this slang doesn't make sense 
in this example . I know `cut the cheese` means  `release intestinal gas`

Does it have another meaning ?

Comment: What effort have you yourself made to find an answer? Have you Googled it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the source of that statement was mixing his idioms. I think he meant to say "cut the mustard" (meaning "to be adequate"), but he accidentally confused "mustard" with "cheese", with funny results -- unless he did it on purpose to be humorous.

Comment: yes, "cut the mustard" is a much more common idiom with this meaning

Answer (score 1):

As might be guessed from context "cut the cheese" can mean "be sufficient" or "do the job".

Comment: While this answer is accurate, it sounds like you're suggesting that the OP should have been able to figure it out from the context, when they obviously were not able to. Could you perhaps explain what part of the context gives clues to the meaning so that the OP can learn? Otherwise it sounds arrogant, to be frank with you, whether that was your intention or not.

Comment: I am sorry this gave the impresison of arrogance, it was not so intended. I did not intend to suggest that the OP should have known this meaning, and I should have phrased this better, It is the whole of the quoted sentence that, in my view, suggests the meaning of the phrase "cut the cheese" in that example. I'm not sure how to be more specific.

Comment: I'm sure you didn't mean it to be arrogant. You have a great reputation that shows how well you answer questions. In any case, I'd suggest describing the scene that the sentence brings to mind and what the intent of the speaker is in that situation - they've received an apology and they're rejecting it. I think that's the context that gives it away. :-)

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Even if "guessing from the context" works sometimes, many other times it does not. Therefore it is much better if you provide an explanation referring to a reliable source (e.g. a dictionary) or from your own experience, if you are a native English speaker.